# Wordpress AD Intergration Error retrieving group

Tags: php, active-directory, wordpress, ldap

[image]

For some odd reason im unable to retrieve group memebers from domain users or any group for that batter.

Base DN is set to  dc=domain,dc=com Ive hits block here. When I use the test tool im able to authenticate [NOTICE] Authentication successfull for "rpimentel@domain.com"

Something is missing. Something simple, that im over looking. What could it be?

```
    // Extend the ADIntegrationPlugin class
    class BulkImportADIntegrationPlugin extends ADIntegrationPlugin {

/**
 * Output formatted debug informations
 * 
 * @param integer level
 * @param string $notice
 */
protected function _log($level = 0, $info = '') {
    if ($level <= $this->_loglevel) {
        switch ($level) {
            case ADI_LOG_DEBUG: 
                $class = 'debug';
                $type  = '[DEBUG]  ';
                break;
            case ADI_LOG_INFO: 
                $class = 'info';
                $type  = '[INFO]   ';
                break;
            case ADI_LOG_NOTICE: 
                $class = 'notice';
                $type = '[NOTICE] ';
                break;
            case ADI_LOG_WARN: 
                $class = 'warn';
                $type = '[WARN]   ';
                break;
            case ADI_LOG_ERROR: 
                $class = 'error';
                $type = '[ERROR]  ';
                break;
            case ADI_LOG_FATAL: 
                $class = 'fatal';
                $type = '[FATAL]  ';
                    break;
            default:
                $class = '';
                $type = '';

        }
        $output = '<span class="'.$class.'">'.$type;
        $output .= str_replace("\n","<br />         ",$info).'</span><br />';
        echo $output;

        if (WP_DEBUG) {
            if ($fh = @fopen($this->_logfile,'a+')) {
                fwrite($fh,$type . str_replace("\n","\n         ",$info) . "\n");
                fclose($fh);
            }
        }       
    }
}


/**
 * Do Bulk Import
 * 
 * @param string $authcode
 * @return bool true on success, false on error
 */
public function bulkimport($authcode)
{
    global $wp_version;
    global $wpdb;

    $this->setLogFile(dirname(__FILE__).'/import.log');

    $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,"-------------------------------------\n".
                             "START OF BULK IMPORT\n".
                             date('Y-m-d / H:i:s')."\n".
                             "-------------------------------------\n");

    $time = time();
    $all_users = array();

    // Is bulk import enabled?
    if (!$this->_bulkimport_enabled) {
        $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,'Bulk Import is disabled.');
        return false;
    }

    // DO we have the correct Auth Code?
    if ($this->_bulkimport_authcode !== $authcode) {
        $this->_log(ADI_LOG_ERROR,'Wrong Auth Code.');
        return false;
    }

    $ad_password = $this->_decrypt($this->_bulkimport_pwd);

    // Log informations
    $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,"Options for adLDAP connection:\n".
                  "- base_dn: $this->_base_dn\n".
                  "- domain_controllers: $this->_domain_controllers\n".
                  "- ad_username: $this->_bulkimport_user\n".
                  "- ad_password: **not shown**\n".
                  "- ad_port: $this->_port\n".
                  "- use_tls: ".(int) $this->_use_tls."\n".
                  "- network timeout: ". $this->_network_timeout);

    // Connect to Active Directory
    try {
        $this->_adldap = @new adLDAP(array(
                    "base_dn" => $this->_base_dn, 
                    "domain_controllers" => explode(';', $this->_domain_controllers),
                    "ad_username" => $this->_bulkimport_user,       // Bulk Import User
                    "ad_password" => $ad_password,                  // password
                    "ad_port" => $this->_port,                      // AD port
                    "use_tls" => $this->_use_tls,                   // secure?
                    "network_timeout" => $this->_network_timeout    // network timeout
                    ));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_log(ADI_LOG_ERROR,'adLDAP exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    $this->_log(ADI_LOG_NOTICE,'adLDAP object created.');
    $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,'Domain Controller: ' . $this->_adldap->get_last_used_dc());

    // Let's give us some more time (60 minutes)
    $max_execution_time = ini_get('max_execution_time');
    if ($max_execution_time < 3600) {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
    }
    if (ini_get('max_execution_time') < 3600) {
        $this->_log(ADI_LOG_ERROR,'Can not increase PHP configuration option "max_execution_time".');
        return false;
    }

    // get all users of the chosen security groups from
    $groups = explode(";",$this->_bulkimport_security_groups);
    if (count($groups) < 1) {
        $this->_log(ADI_LOG_WARN,'No security group.');
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($groups AS $group) {
        // get all members of group
        $group = trim($group);
        if ($group != '')  {
            // do we have a groupid?
            if (($pos = stripos($group,'id:')) !== false) {
                $pgid = substr($group,$pos+3);
                $members = $this->_adldap->group_members_by_primarygroupid($pgid, true);
            } else {
                $members = $this->_adldap->group_members($group, true);
            }
            if ($members) {
                $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,count($members).' Members of group "'.$group.'".');
                $this->_log(ADI_LOG_DEBUG,'Members of group "'.$group.'": ' . implode(', ',$members));
                foreach ($members AS $user) {
                    $all_users[strtolower($user)] = $user;
                }
            } else {
                $this->_log(ADI_LOG_ERROR,'Error retrieving group members for group "'.$group.'".');
            }
        } else {
            $this->_log(ADI_LOG_WARN,'No group. Nothing to do.');
        } 
    }

    // Adding all local users with non empty entry adi_samaccountname in usermeta
    $blogusers=$wpdb->get_results( 
        '
        SELECT
            users.user_login
        FROM
            '. $wpdb->users . ' users
        INNER JOIN
            ' . $wpdb->usermeta ." meta ON meta.user_id = users.ID
        where
            meta.meta_key = 'adi_samaccountname'
            AND
            meta.meta_value IS NOT NULL
            AND
            meta.meta_value <> ''
            AND
            users.ID <> 1
        "
    );
    if (is_array($blogusers)) {
        foreach ($blogusers AS $user) {
            $all_users[strtolower($user->user_login)] = $user->user_login;
        }
    }   


    $elapsed_time = time() - $time;
    $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,'Number of users to import/update: '.count($all_users).' (list generated in '. $elapsed_time .' seconds)');

    if (version_compare($wp_version, '3.1', '<')) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'registration.php');
    }


    // import all relevant users
    $added_users = 0;
    $updated_users = 0;
    foreach ($all_users AS $username) {

        $ad_username = $username;

        // getting user data
        //$user = get_userdatabylogin($username); // deprecated
        $user = get_user_by('login', $username);

        // role
        $user_role = $this->_get_user_role_equiv($ad_username); // important: use $ad_username not $username

        // userinfo from AD
        $this->_log(ADI_LOG_DEBUG, 'ATTRIBUTES TO LOAD: '.print_r($this->_all_user_attributes, true));
        $userinfo = $this->_adldap->user_info($ad_username, $this->_all_user_attributes);
        $userinfo = $userinfo[0];
        $this->_log(ADI_LOG_DEBUG,"USERINFO[0]: \n".print_r($userinfo,true));

        if (empty($userinfo)) {
            $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,'User "' . $ad_username . '" not found in Active Directory.');
            if (isset($user->ID) && ($this->_disable_users)) {
                $this->_log(ADI_LOG_WARN,'User "' . $username . '" disabled.');
                $this->_disable_user($user->ID, sprintf(__('User "%s" not found in Active Directory.', 'ad-integration'), $username));
            }

        } else {

            // Only user accounts (UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT is set and other account flags are unset)
            if (($userinfo["useraccountcontrol"][0] & (UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT | ADI_NO_UF_NORMAL_ACOUNT)) == UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT) { 
               //&& (($userinfo["useraccountcontrol"][0] & ADI_NO_UF_NORMAL_ACOUNT)  == 0)) {

                // users with flag UF_SMARTCARD_REQUIRED have no password so they can not logon with ADI
                if (($userinfo["useraccountcontrol"][0] & UF_SMARTCARD_REQUIRED) == 0) {

                    // get display name
                    $display_name = $this->_get_display_name_from_AD($username, $userinfo);

                    // create new users or update them
                    if (!$user OR (strtolower($user->user_login) != strtolower($username))) { // use strtolower!!!
                        $user_id = $this->_create_user($ad_username, $userinfo, $display_name, $user_role, '', true);
                        $added_users++;
                    } else {
                        $user_id = $this->_update_user($ad_username, $userinfo, $display_name, $user_role, '', true);
                        $updated_users++;
                    }

                    // load user object (this shouldn't be necessary)
                    if (!$user_id) {
                        $user_id = username_exists($username);
                        $this->_log(ADI_LOG_NOTICE,'user_id: '.$user_id);
                    }

                    // if the user is disabled
                    if (($userinfo["useraccountcontrol"][0] & UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE) == UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE)
                    {
                        $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,'The user "' . $username .'" is disabled in Active Directory.');
                        if ($this->_disable_users) {
                            $this->_log(ADI_LOG_WARN,'Disabling user "' . $username .'".');
                            $this->_disable_user($user_id, sprintf(__('User "%s" is disabled in Active Directory.', 'ad-integration'), $username));
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Enable user / turn off user_disabled
                        $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,'Enabling user "' . $username .'".');
                        $this->_enable_user($user_id);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Flag UF_SMARTCARD_REQUIRED is set
                    $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,'The user "' . $username .'" requires a SmartCard to logon.');
                    if (isset($user->ID) && ($this->_disable_users)) {
                        $this->_log(ADI_LOG_WARN,'Disabling user "' . $username .'".');
                        $this->_disable_user($user->ID, sprintf(__('User "%s" requires a SmartCard to logon.', 'ad-integration'), $username));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // not a normal user account
                $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,'The user "' . $username .'" has no normal user account.');
                if (isset($user->ID) && ($this->_disable_users)) {
                    $this->_log(ADI_LOG_WARN,'Disabling user "' . $username .'".');
                    $this->_disable_user($user->ID, sprintf(__('User "%s" has no normal user account.', 'ad-integration'), $username));
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    // Logging  
    $elapsed_time = time() - $time;
    $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,$added_users . ' Users added.');
    $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,$updated_users . ' Users updated.');
    $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,'In '. $elapsed_time . ' seconds.');

    $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,"-------------------------------------\n".
                             "END OF BULK IMPORT\n".
                             date('Y-m-d / H:i:s')."\n".
                             "-------------------------------------\n");        

    return true;
}
```

It looks like this is where I fails. But why wouldn't it be able to get group?

```
    foreach ($groups AS $group) {
    // get all members of group
    $group = trim($group);
    if ($group != '')  {
        // do we have a groupid?
        if (($pos = stripos($group,'id:')) !== false) {
            $pgid = substr($group,$pos+3);
            $members = $this->_adldap->group_members_by_primarygroupid($pgid, true);
        } else {
            $members = $this->_adldap->group_members($group, true);
        }
        if ($members) {
            $this->_log(ADI_LOG_INFO,count($members).' Members of group "'.$group.'".');
            $this->_log(ADI_LOG_DEBUG,'Members of group "'.$group.'": ' . implode(', ',$members));
            foreach ($members AS $user) {
                $all_users[strtolower($user)] = $user;
            }
        } else {
            $this->_log(ADI_LOG_ERROR,'Error retrieving group members for group "'.$group.'".');
        }
```

Comment: Are you using the PHP LDAP code? Can you post the relevant portions of the plugin?

Comment: Yes. Ive added the Bulkimport php code.

Comment: I removed  `$ad_password = $this->_decrypt($this->_bulkimport_pwd);` and added `$ad_password = 'my_password_here';`just out of curiosity and it worked. some this password decrypt is broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed 
        $ad_password = $this->_decrypt($this->_bulkimport_pwd); 
and added 
        $ad_password = 'my_password_here';

And it worked

Seems that this decrypt password is broken.

[INFO]   1000 Members of group "id:513".
[INFO]   Number of users to import/update: 3439

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I filled twice the field "Bulk Import User Password". I launched the bulk import, which failed (all the users were disabled!). My Apache log below:

> PHP Warning:  mcrypt_decrypt(): Key of size 27 not supported by this
>   algorithm.Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported in
>   /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/active-directory-integration/ad-integration.php

The problem seems come from the function `mcrypt` used to encrypt the password. We can see in the file `ad-integration.php` that the function used the Wordpress constant `AUTH_SALT`, which is defined by default like "put your unique phrase here", thus 27 char. So I defined this constant with a string of 32 char (you can define this in `wp-config.php`). I refilled the Bulk Import User Password and it works.